# Renaming files with different Names depending upon different match cases in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, file-rename

I'm a newbie at python, I'm trying to write a python code to rename multiple files with different names depending upon different match cases, here's my code

```
for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(inputpath)):
    if(match(".*"716262_2.*$"),file):
      dstgco="Test1"+"DateHere"+".xls"
      gnupgCommandOp=gnupgCommand(os.rename(os.path.join(inputpath,file),os.path.join(inputpath,dstgco)))
      returnCode = call(gnupgCommandop)
    

   if(match(".*"270811_2.*$"),file):
    dstgmo="Test2"+"DateHere"+".xls"
    gnupgCommandOp=gnupgCommand(os.rename(os.path.join(inputpath,file),os.path.join(inputpath,dstgmo)))
          returnCode = call(gnupgCommandop)
```

currently what is happening is only one file is getting renamed which is `Test2 DateHere` with `str object is not a callable error`, my requirement is to rename files present at the location depending on the different match cases, I'm writing incorrect for loop or if statements?
things I have tried :

1. used incremental count
2. used glob
3. used only `os.listdir` and not `enumerate`

seems like it is matching the first statement and breaking on the next retrieval, may be I wrote If statements wrong
I can't debug this since I'm calling this code from an internal tool using a bat file.
can someone please help me out with this, I know only a single gnupgCommandOp should be used, is my syntax is wrong? is what would be a better way to achieve this?